# Get inner SELECT result as ResultSet from INSERT INTO SELECT statement in mySQL Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

I have 2 DBs, `Database A` and `Database B`.

**What I want to achieve:**

1. build records from `Database A` and insert them to `Database B`
2. Process those records in my java app

**What I'm currently doing:**
I use two separate queries:

For (1) I use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`
For (2) I perform another `SELECT`.

My solution works but it isn't optimal since I'm getting the records from `Database A` twice (instead of just one time).

Is there a way to execute the `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` and get the inner select result as a `ResultSet`?

I know I can perform only a `SELECT` and then insert the records in a batch, but thats a bit cumbersome and I want to find out if there's a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cleaner solution look more cumbersome than simple read and write operation.

As you have to manipulate data in database B. You simply do this

1. Read Data from A to your app
2. Process data
3. Write data to B from your app

Then you have singe read single write and is simple.

You can not gain the result of `INSERT INTO` as Result set as this is `INSERT` statement

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, I do not think that this is possible. What you are trying to achieve are two distinct operations i.e. an `INSERT` and a `SELECT`. However you cut it you are still going have to do at least one `INSERT` and one `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

use this for two database
INSERT INTO Database2 (field1,field2,field3){
  SELECT * FROM Database1;);

Both the database have the same field name.